# what is the difference in resolver valid time and resolver_timeout in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have this nginx configuration entry.

```
http {
  resolver 172.17.42.1 valid=600s;
  resolver_timeout 60s;
```

In this configuration there 2 two different timeouts. 
The nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) does not make it clear to me what is the difference between **valid** and **resolver_timeout**.

Can someone explain in detail?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`resolve_timeout` sets how long NGINX will wait for answer from resolver (DNS).

`valid` flag means how long NGINX will consider answer from resolver as valid and will not ask resolver for that period.

In your example, let's say NGINX want to resolve `example.com`. It will ask resolver (172.17.42.1) and if resolver doesn't answer within 60 seconds NGINX will fail this request (and probably show you 500 error). Let's say resolver successfully answered, then NGINX will remember that answer for 10 minutes. If NGINX needs to resolve `example.com` within that time, then it will use previous answer instead of asking resolver again.

Comment: Hi,  what happen it the example.com IP has been changed in between, and not able to connect old IP, so service will be down for 10 min or it will ask resolver again in case of error.